# Problems Linking a File

Tags: html

I am trying to get from my mjcbank.htm. to link to products.shtml.  And can not figure it out.  I am using ssi and the locations are noted below.

```
<li><a href="../products.shtml">Products</a></li> (this does not work)
<li><a href="../aboutus.shtml">About Us</a></li>
```

The file location is

advancedwebdesign/products.shtml

The navigation on the ssit is

adcancedwebdesign/ssifooter/navigation.shtml

the full server location is..

https://wiki.cit.iupui.edu/~mjcrawle/advancedwebdesign/mjcbank.shtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your pages are on the same folder, try `href="products.shtml"`

Comment: Yes.. You are correct.. that was stupid of me.  I decide to change try it 2 minutes after my poste.... Go Figure!

Comment: I feel like an idiot... Sorry world for that one.

Comment: Yea, path of the navigation SSI file is for the mjcbank.shtml to include, the actual path of the hyperlinks used in the navigation should be with reference from the file including it and not itself.